# Bluetooth LE: setting characteristic to byte array sends wrong values

Tags: c++, c, windows, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using `Bluetoothleapis.h` to communicate with a custom Bluetooth Low Energy device.

The device is setup the following way:

- Custom GATT service
- Characteristic#1 Read/Write (expects 3 bytes)
- Characteristic#2 Read/Notify (returns 1 byte)

I am able get proper values from characteristic#2. However, when I try to send data to characteristic#1, the device receives weird data.

The characteristic is responsible for 3 parameters of a real-life object (imagine a light with intensity, color, etc). (0,0,0) should respond to the "light" being off, but if I send the (0,0,0), I can see that the device receives something else (I cannot tell what exactly, but it is not off). The state does not seem to change no matter what values I send.

I have tried alternating between write and write-no-response, both produce the same result.

`GetCharacteristicValue` interestingly returns a `charValueDataSize` of 8, even though the characteristic is known to accept only 3 bytes. Coincidentally, the size for the 1-byte read-only characteristic is 9, for some reason.

I have tried limiting the size of the `WriteValue` to only 3 bytes, but in this case I get an invalid argument error. Answers elsewhere on StackOverflow have indicated that I need to use the one I get from GetCharacteristicValue, and transfer my data into there.

Given the fact that the real object's state does not change no matter which values are sent, I suspect that the problem is somewhere with the way I set up the byte array to transfer the data.

Furthermore, calling `GetCharacteristicValue` even after setting it returns an empty array.

I am not sure what values are actually being sent, and I lack the hardware to track them via Wireshark.

```
DWORD WriteValueToCharacteristic(__in const HANDLE deviceHandle, 
__in const CharacteristicData* pCharData, 
__in const UCHAR* writeBuffer,
__in const USHORT bufferSize,
__in const BOOL noResponse )
{
HRESULT hr;
PBTH_LE_GATT_CHARACTERISTIC pCharacteristic = pCharData->pCharacteristic;
USHORT charValueDataSize;

hr = BluetoothGATTGetCharacteristicValue
(
    deviceHandle,
    pCharacteristic,
    0,
    NULL,
    &charValueDataSize,
    BLUETOOTH_GATT_FLAG_NONE    
);

if (hr != HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_MORE_DATA))
{
    Log(L"BluetoothGATTSetCharacteristicValue returned error %d", hr);
    FormatBluetoothError(hr);
    return -1;
}
PBTH_LE_GATT_CHARACTERISTIC_VALUE pWriteValue = (PBTH_LE_GATT_CHARACTERISTIC_VALUE)HeapAlloc
(
    GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, charValueDataSize + sizeof(BTH_LE_GATT_CHARACTERISTIC_VALUE)
);

if (pWriteValue == NULL)
{
    Log(L"Out of memory.");
    return -1;
}

hr = BluetoothGATTGetCharacteristicValue
(
    deviceHandle,
    pCharacteristic,
    charValueDataSize,
    pWriteValue,
    NULL,
    BLUETOOTH_GATT_FLAG_FORCE_READ_FROM_DEVICE
);

memcpy(pWriteValue->Data, writeBuffer, bufferSize);
ULONG flags = noResponse == TRUE ? BLUETOOTH_GATT_FLAG_WRITE_WITHOUT_RESPONSE : 0;

hr = BluetoothGATTSetCharacteristicValue
(
    deviceHandle, 
    pCharacteristic, 
    pWriteValue, 
    NULL,
    flags   
);

if (hr != S_OK)
{
    Log(L"BluetoothGATTSetCharacteristicValue returned error %d", hr);
    FormatBluetoothError(hr);
    return -1;
}
HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, pWriteValue);
return ERROR_SUCCESS;
}
```

`SetCharacteristicValue` returns `S_OK`, producing no errors.

Both reading and writing to the characteristic work fine when using a BLE app on Android.

#### Update 1

@Shubham pointed out it might be an endianness issue, so I tried to substitute memcpy for the following:

```
int j = 0;
int i = charValueDataSize - 1;
while (j < bufferSize)
{
    pWriteValue->Data[i] = writeBuffer[j];
    --i;
    ++j;
}
```

However, nothing changed.

#### Update 2

I have incorporated the changes as per [emil's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56936632/5650868), and it worked! Posting the full code in case somebody else experiences the same issue.

Incidentally, even though the characteristic is marked as Writable: true, Writable-no-response: false, I need to set the flags to no-response in order for the values to get sent.

```
DWORD WriteValueToCharacteristic(__in const HANDLE deviceHandle, __in const CharacteristicData* pCharData, __in const UCHAR* writeBuffer, __in const USHORT bufferSize, __in const BOOL noResponse)
{
HRESULT hr;
PBTH_LE_GATT_CHARACTERISTIC pCharacteristic = pCharData->pCharacteristic;
USHORT charValueDataSize = 512;

PBTH_LE_GATT_CHARACTERISTIC_VALUE pWriteValue = (PBTH_LE_GATT_CHARACTERISTIC_VALUE)HeapAlloc
(
    GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, charValueDataSize + sizeof(BTH_LE_GATT_CHARACTERISTIC_VALUE)
);

if (pWriteValue == NULL)
{
    Log(L"Out of memory.");
    return -1;
}

hr = BluetoothGATTGetCharacteristicValue
(
    deviceHandle,
    pCharacteristic,
    (ULONG)charValueDataSize,
    pWriteValue,
    NULL,
    BLUETOOTH_GATT_FLAG_FORCE_READ_FROM_DEVICE
);
if (bufferSize > pWriteValue->DataSize)
{
   if(pWriteValue->DataSize == 0) 
    {
        pWriteValue->DataSize = bufferSize;
    }
}
// after the first write, DataSize stays as 3
//pWriteValue->DataSize here is 3, as expected
//buffer size is also 3
memcpy(pWriteValue->Data, writeBuffer, bufferSize);
ULONG flags = noResponse == TRUE ? BLUETOOTH_GATT_FLAG_WRITE_WITHOUT_RESPONSE : 0;

hr = BluetoothGATTSetCharacteristicValue
(
    deviceHandle, 
    pCharacteristic, 
    pWriteValue, 
    NULL,
    flags   
);

if (hr != S_OK)
{
    Log(L"BluetoothGATTSetCharacteristicValue returned error %d", hr);
    FormatBluetoothError(hr);
    HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, pWriteValue);
    return -1;
}
HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, pWriteValue);
return ERROR_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: I'm just guessing, may be the [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) issue?

Comment: @Shubham, I tried substituting the memcpy for the code in Update #1, but nothing changed.

Comment: could you show what data you sent and what data you received

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is that you first set charValueDataSize to 512 + sizeof(BTH_LE_GATT_CHARACTERISTIC_VALUE) (maximum possible), and skip the initial read that would get the size. Then check pWriteValue->DataSize to get the actual size after a successful read. Also make sure you free your memory even in case of error.

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked after I incorporated your suggestions!